# Where to look for information on technological advances in lithium-ion batteries?

Tags: reference-request

For my philosophy of science class, I'm looking for references that will provide a historical / science philosophical insight on the development and advances of lithium-ion batteries. For now, I imagine two types of such sources:

- encyclopedias on technology. I will read [Encyclopedia of Electrochemical Power Sources](http://store.elsevier.com/Encyclopedia-of-Electrochemical-Power-Sources/isbn-9780444520937/), will do my best to find something in the Encyclopedia of History of Technology or Encyclopedia of Electrochemistry. Any more books that I could look into?
- review articles. For now, I have [Goodenough, 2009](http://pubs.acs.org/doi/abs/10.1021/cm901452z), but that doesn't seem to be sufficient to me.

Am I missing any other types of references? I feel that I will possibly need something more on the philosophy of science side of things, not purely technical.

Comment: Use this work as well: [Electrical Energy Storage and Intercalation Chemistry](http://authors.library.caltech.edu/5456/1/hrst.mit.edu/hrs/materials/public/Whittingham/Whit_publs/Whit_Science_1974.htm) 1976 by Stanley Whittingham. I chased the link from the [wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lithium-ion_battery#History). They say this  was the first proposal for a lithium battery. Chase down the other journal papers cited in the wiki. Scientific journal publications especially from the 1970's when the idea was being developed seem a good bet, then try to find a scan of each title.

Comment: This is interesting, at first glance lithium-ion batteries seem like an odd subject for philosophy of science. Could you explain the angle?

Comment: @Conifold, my Material Science PhD is in the field of lithium-ion batteries. For the philosophy class, we are requested for a philosophy of science take on our research. I hope that I could find some general sources on how people search for novel materials and fit the specific information on Li-ion batteries and their electrode materials into it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have written a report in question, though it turned out to be more on the history side than on the philosophy side, listing the important technological advances and breakthroughs.

The best introduction to the history of lithium-ion batteries is [the corresponding section of the Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lithium-ion_battery#History), which gives a good timeline of achievements. Also, [this *Nature* article](http://www.nature.com/nature/journal/v407/n6803/full/407496a0.html) is important because it is the first mention of nanostructured materials for lithium-ion batteries.

My report is [posted here](https://svavil.wordpress.com/2016/03/26/technological-advances-in-lithium-ion-battery-research/) for anyone interested.